# select conditions what are present or empty

Tags: cakephp-3.0

On a CakePHP 3 project I want to run a select in my controller. The user could choose different filtering conditions for the select. If a condition is not choosed, I do not need it in my select.

Now I have something like this

```
$where = [];

if ( ! empty($this->request->data['fcontact_id'])){
    $where['Histories.contact_id'] = $this->request->data['fcontact_id'];
}
if ( ! empty($this->request->data['fuser_id'])){
    $where['Histories.user_id'] = $this->request->data['fuser_id'];
}
if ( ! empty($this->request->data['fgroup_id'])){
    $where['Histories.group_id'] = $this->request->data['fgroup_id'];
}

$histories = $this->Histories->find()->where($where);
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: "_better_"? That sounds as if you are asking for opinions. I'd suggest that you explain the problem that you are having with it (like for example it not being very DRY). And you may want to check **https://github.com/CakeDC/search/tree/3.0**

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of the available search plugins:

https://github.com/friendsofcake/search

or

https://github.com/skie/plum_search

or

https://github.com/CakeDC/search